# Need To Center div

Tags: css

I need to center my div no matter what screen size and it will not center. I have tried the normal `margin: 0 auto;` and `text-align:center` and a few other things but it will not center. I believe it's because of the confetti I have on the screen. Any help would be awesome on how to center this.

Here is the CSS code I am using:

```
 <style id='dt-main-inline-css' type='text/css'>
 body {
 background: transparent;
 }
 .centerit {
 width: 100%;
 max-width: 900px;
 text-align:center;
 }

 #content {
 text-align: center;
 position: absolute;
 }

 canvas {
 display: block;
 zindex: 1;
 pointer-events: none;
 }

 .top-words-home3{
 text-align:center;
 font-size: 80px;
 line-height:80px;
 color:#ff3754;
 -webkit-animation: glow .5s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
 -moz-animation: glow .5s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
 animation: glow .5s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
 }

 @-webkit-keyframes glow {
 from {
 text-shadow: 0 0 1px #000, 0 0 2px #000, 0 0 3px #e60073, 0 0 3px #e60073, 0 0 3px #e60073, 0 0 9px 
 #e60073, 0 0 3px #e60073;
 }
 to {
 text-shadow: 0 0 5px #000, 0 0 7px #ff0060, 0 0 10px #ff0060, 0 0 12px #ffcc00, 0 0 14px #ff8a1a, 0 0 16px #ff8a1a, 0 0 18px #ff8a1a;
 }
 }

 .top-words-home4{
 text-align:center;
 font-size:33px;
 line-height:33px;
 color:#ff3754;
 -webkit-animation: glow2 .3s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
 -moz-animation: glow2 .3s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
 animation: glow2 .3s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
 }

 @-webkit-keyframes glow2 {
 from {
 text-shadow: 0 0 1px #0099ff, 0 0 2px #0099ff, 0 0 3px #99ffee, 0 0 4px #99ffee, 0 0 6px #99ffee, 0 0 8px #99ffee, 0 0 10px #99ffee;
 }
 to {
 text-shadow: 0 0 1px #0099ff, 0 0 2px #00ccee, 0 0 3px #00ccee, 0 0 4px #00ccee, 0 0 6px #00cc88, 0 0 8px #00cc88, 0 0 10px #00cc88;
 }
 }
 </style>
```

Here is the Code for the Confetti so you can see it.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[
     (function () {
     // globals
     var canvas;
     var ctx;
     var W;
     var H;
     var mp = 150; //max particles
     var particles = [];
     var angle = 0;
     var tiltAngle = 0;
     var confettiActive = true;
    var animationComplete = true;
    var deactivationTimerHandler;
    var reactivationTimerHandler;
    var animationHandler;

    // objects

    var particleColors = {
        colorOptions: ["DodgerBlue", "OliveDrab", "Gold", "pink", "SlateBlue", "lightblue", "Violet", "PaleGreen", "SteelBlue", "SandyBrown", "Chocolate", "Crimson"],
        colorIndex: 0,
        colorIncrementer: 0,
        colorThreshold: 10,
        getColor: function () {
            if (this.colorIncrementer >= 10) {
                this.colorIncrementer = 0;
                this.colorIndex++;
                if (this.colorIndex >= this.colorOptions.length) {
                    this.colorIndex = 0;
                }
            }
            this.colorIncrementer++;
            return this.colorOptions[this.colorIndex];
        }
    }

    function confettiParticle(color) {
        this.x = Math.random() * W; // x-coordinate
        this.y = (Math.random() * H) - H; //y-coordinate
        this.r = RandomFromTo(10, 30); //radius;
        this.d = (Math.random() * mp) + 10; //density;
        this.color = color;
        this.tilt = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) - 10;
        this.tiltAngleIncremental = (Math.random() * 0.07) + .05;
        this.tiltAngle = 0;

        this.draw = function () {
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.lineWidth = this.r / 2;
            ctx.strokeStyle = this.color;
            ctx.moveTo(this.x + this.tilt + (this.r / 4), this.y);
            ctx.lineTo(this.x + this.tilt, this.y + this.tilt + (this.r / 4));
            return ctx.stroke();
        }
    }

    $(document).ready(function () {
        SetGlobals();
        InitializeButton();
        InitializeConfetti();

        $(window).resize(function () {
            W = window.innerWidth;
            H = window.innerHeight;
            canvas.width = W;
            canvas.height = H;
        });

    });

    function InitializeButton() {
        $('#stopButton').click(DeactivateConfetti);
        $('#startButton').click(RestartConfetti);
    }

    function SetGlobals() {
        canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
        ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        W = window.innerWidth;
        H = window.innerHeight;
        canvas.width = W;
        canvas.height = H;
    }

    function InitializeConfetti() {
        particles = [];
        animationComplete = false;
        for (var i = 0; i < mp; i++) {
            var particleColor = particleColors.getColor();
            particles.push(new confettiParticle(particleColor));
        }
        StartConfetti();
    }

    function Draw() {
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, W, H);
        var results = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < mp; i++) {
            (function (j) {
                results.push(particles[j].draw());
            })(i);
        }
        Update();

        return results;
    }

    function RandomFromTo(from, to) {
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * (to - from + 1) + from);
    }


    function Update() {
        var remainingFlakes = 0;
        var particle;
        angle += 0.01;
        tiltAngle += 0.1;

        for (var i = 0; i < mp; i++) {
            particle = particles[i];
            if (animationComplete) return;

            if (!confettiActive && particle.y < -15) {
                particle.y = H + 100;
                continue;
            }

            stepParticle(particle, i);

            if (particle.y <= H) {
                remainingFlakes++;
            }
            CheckForReposition(particle, i);
        }

        if (remainingFlakes === 0) {
            StopConfetti();
        }
    }

    function CheckForReposition(particle, index) {
        if ((particle.x > W + 20 || particle.x < -20 || particle.y > H) && confettiActive) {
            if (index % 5 > 0 || index % 2 == 0) //66.67% of the flakes
            {
                repositionParticle(particle, Math.random() * W, -10, Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) - 10);
            } else {
                if (Math.sin(angle) > 0) {
                    //Enter from the left
                    repositionParticle(particle, -5, Math.random() * H, Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) - 10);
                } else {
                    //Enter from the right
                    repositionParticle(particle, W + 5, Math.random() * H, Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) - 10);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    function stepParticle(particle, particleIndex) {
        particle.tiltAngle += particle.tiltAngleIncremental;
        particle.y += (Math.cos(angle + particle.d) + 3 + particle.r / 2) / 2;
        particle.x += Math.sin(angle);
        particle.tilt = (Math.sin(particle.tiltAngle - (particleIndex / 3))) * 15;
    }

    function repositionParticle(particle, xCoordinate, yCoordinate, tilt) {
        particle.x = xCoordinate;
        particle.y = yCoordinate;
        particle.tilt = tilt;
    }

    function StartConfetti() {
        W = window.innerWidth;
        H = window.innerHeight;
        canvas.width = W;
        canvas.height = H;
        (function animloop() {
            if (animationComplete) return null;
            animationHandler = requestAnimFrame(animloop);
            return Draw();
        })();
    }

    function ClearTimers() {
        clearTimeout(reactivationTimerHandler);
        clearTimeout(animationHandler);
    }

    function DeactivateConfetti() {
        confettiActive = false;
        ClearTimers();
    }

    function StopConfetti() {
        animationComplete = true;
        if (ctx == undefined) return;
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, W, H);
    }

    function RestartConfetti() {
        ClearTimers();
        StopConfetti();
        reactivationTimerHandler = setTimeout(function () {
            confettiActive = true;
            animationComplete = false;
            InitializeConfetti();
        }, 100);

    }

    window.requestAnimFrame = (function () {
        return window.requestAnimationFrame || window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || window.mozRequestAnimationFrame || window.oRequestAnimationFrame || window.msRequestAnimationFrame || function (callback) {
            return window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
        };
    })();
})();



  //]]></script>
```

Here is the HTML code to tie it together:

```
<div class="centerit">
<div id="content">
<br /><br />
<h2 style="color: #ff2828;text-align: center;font-family:Bangers;font-weight:400;font-style:normal" class="top-words-home3" >Congratulations and Thank You!</h2>
<br />
<h3 class="top-words-home4" style="text-align: center; color: blue; font-weight: bold;"><strong>Watch Your Email Inbox & Spam Folder For An Email From Us!</strong></h3>
<br />
<p style="font-size:28px;">Please be advised that we have very limited seating for this webinar.<br />Be sure to look for the followups for this webinar on the day of the webinar and follow the directions very carefully.</p>
<br /><br />
</div>
</div>
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following to  your top level wrapping element:

```
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
width: 100%;
```

This is CSS `flexbox` in action. You can read more about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox).

Here's a working snippet

```js
(function () {
    // globals
    var canvas;
    var ctx;
    var W;
    var H;
    var mp = 150; //max particles
    var particles = [];
    var angle = 0;
    var tiltAngle = 0;
    var confettiActive = true;
    var animationComplete = true;
    var deactivationTimerHandler;
    var reactivationTimerHandler;
    var animationHandler;
       
    // objects
       
    var particleColors = {
        colorOptions: ["DodgerBlue", "OliveDrab", "Gold", "pink", "SlateBlue", "lightblue", "Violet", "PaleGreen", "SteelBlue", "SandyBrown", "Chocolate", "Crimson"],
        colorIndex: 0,
        colorIncrementer: 0,
        colorThreshold: 10,
        getColor: function () {
             if (this.colorIncrementer >= 10) {
                  this.colorIncrementer = 0;
                  this.colorIndex++;
                  if (this.colorIndex >= this.colorOptions.length) {
                      this.colorIndex = 0;
                  }
             }
              this.colorIncrementer++;
              return this.colorOptions[this.colorIndex];
           }
       }
       
       function confettiParticle(color) {
          this.x = Math.random() * W; // x-coordinate
          this.y = (Math.random() * H) - H; //y-coordinate
          this.r = RandomFromTo(10, 30); //radius;
          this.d = (Math.random() * mp) + 10; //density;
          this.color = color;
          this.tilt = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) - 10;
          this.tiltAngleIncremental = (Math.random() * 0.07) + .05;
          this.tiltAngle = 0;
       
          this.draw = function () {
              ctx.beginPath();
              ctx.lineWidth = this.r / 2;
              ctx.strokeStyle = this.color;
              ctx.moveTo(this.x + this.tilt + (this.r / 4), this.y);
              ctx.lineTo(this.x + this.tilt, this.y + this.tilt + (this.r / 4));
              return ctx.stroke();
           }
      }
       
       $(document).ready(function () {
           SetGlobals();
           InitializeButton();
           InitializeConfetti();
       
           $(window).resize(function () {
              W = window.innerWidth;
              H = window.innerHeight;
              canvas.width = W;
              canvas.height = H;
          });
       
      });
       
      function InitializeButton() {
          $('#stopButton').click(DeactivateConfetti);
          $('#startButton').click(RestartConfetti);
      }
       
      function SetGlobals() {
          canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
          ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
          W = window.innerWidth;
          H = window.innerHeight;
          canvas.width = W;
          canvas.height = H;
      }
       
      function InitializeConfetti() {
          particles = [];
          animationComplete = false;
          for (var i = 0; i < mp; i++) {
              var particleColor = particleColors.getColor();
              particles.push(new confettiParticle(particleColor));
         }
           StartConfetti();
       }
       
       function Draw() {
          ctx.clearRect(0, 0, W, H);
          var results = [];
          for (var i = 0; i < mp; i++) {
             (function (j) {
                  results.push(particles[j].draw());
              })(i);
          }
               Update();
       
               return results;
           }
       
           function RandomFromTo(from, to) {
               return Math.floor(Math.random() * (to - from + 1) + from);
           }
       
       
           function Update() {
               var remainingFlakes = 0;
               var particle;
               angle += 0.01;
               tiltAngle += 0.1;
       
               for (var i = 0; i < mp; i++) {
                   particle = particles[i];
                   if (animationComplete) return;
       
                   if (!confettiActive && particle.y < -15) {
                       particle.y = H + 100;
                       continue;
                   }
       
                   stepParticle(particle, i);
       
                   if (particle.y <= H) {
                       remainingFlakes++;
                   }
                   CheckForReposition(particle, i);
               }
       
               if (remainingFlakes === 0) {
                   StopConfetti();
               }
           }
       
           function CheckForReposition(particle, index) {
               if ((particle.x > W + 20 || particle.x < -20 || particle.y > H) && confettiActive) {
                   if (index % 5 > 0 || index % 2 == 0) //66.67% of the flakes
                   {
                       repositionParticle(particle, Math.random() * W, -10, Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) - 10);
                   } else {
                       if (Math.sin(angle) > 0) {
                           //Enter from the left
                           repositionParticle(particle, -5, Math.random() * H, Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) - 10);
                       } else {
                           //Enter from the right
                           repositionParticle(particle, W + 5, Math.random() * H, Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) - 10);
                       }
                   }
               }
           }
           function stepParticle(particle, particleIndex) {
               particle.tiltAngle += particle.tiltAngleIncremental;
               particle.y += (Math.cos(angle + particle.d) + 3 + particle.r / 2) / 2;
               particle.x += Math.sin(angle);
               particle.tilt = (Math.sin(particle.tiltAngle - (particleIndex / 3))) * 15;
           }
       
           function repositionParticle(particle, xCoordinate, yCoordinate, tilt) {
               particle.x = xCoordinate;
               particle.y = yCoordinate;
               particle.tilt = tilt;
           }
       
           function StartConfetti() {
               W = window.innerWidth;
               H = window.innerHeight;
               canvas.width = W;
               canvas.height = H;
               (function animloop() {
                   if (animationComplete) return null;
                   animationHandler = requestAnimFrame(animloop);
                   return Draw();
               })();
           }
       
           function ClearTimers() {
               clearTimeout(reactivationTimerHandler);
               clearTimeout(animationHandler);
           }
       
           function DeactivateConfetti() {
               confettiActive = false;
               ClearTimers();
           }
       
           function StopConfetti() {
               animationComplete = true;
               if (ctx == undefined) return;
               ctx.clearRect(0, 0, W, H);
           }
       
           function RestartConfetti() {
               ClearTimers();
               StopConfetti();
               reactivationTimerHandler = setTimeout(function () {
                   confettiActive = true;
                   animationComplete = false;
                   InitializeConfetti();
               }, 100);
       
           }
       
           window.requestAnimFrame = (function () {
               return window.requestAnimationFrame || window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || window.mozRequestAnimationFrame || window.oRequestAnimationFrame || window.msRequestAnimationFrame || function (callback) {
                   return window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
               };
           })();
       })();
```

```css
body {
    background: transparent;
}

.centerit {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 100%;
}
       
#content {
   text-align: center;
   position: absolute;
}
       
canvas {
   display: block;
   zindex: 1;
   pointer-events: none;
}
       
.top-words-home3{
   text-align:center;
   font-size: 80px;
   line-height:80px;
   color:#ff3754;
   -webkit-animation: glow .5s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
   -moz-animation: glow .5s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
   animation: glow .5s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
}
       
@-webkit-keyframes glow {
    from {
        text-shadow: 0 0 1px #000, 0 0 2px #000, 0 0 3px #e60073, 0 0 3px #e60073, 0 0 3px #e60073, 0 0 9px 
        #e60073, 0 0 3px #e60073;
    }
    to {
        text-shadow: 0 0 5px #000, 0 0 7px #ff0060, 0 0 10px #ff0060, 0 0 12px #ffcc00, 0 0 14px #ff8a1a, 0 0 16px #ff8a1a, 0 0 18px #ff8a1a;
    }
}
       
.top-words-home4{
     text-align:center;
     font-size:33px;
     line-height:33px;
     color:#ff3754;
     -webkit-animation: glow2 .3s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
     -moz-animation: glow2 .3s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
     animation: glow2 .3s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
}
       
@-webkit-keyframes glow2 {
     from {
        text-shadow: 0 0 1px #0099ff, 0 0 2px #0099ff, 0 0 3px #99ffee, 0 0 4px #99ffee, 0 0 6px #99ffee, 0 0 8px #99ffee, 0 0 10px #99ffee;
     }
     to {
        text-shadow: 0 0 1px #0099ff, 0 0 2px #00ccee, 0 0 3px #00ccee, 0 0 4px #00ccee, 0 0 6px #00cc88, 0 0 8px #00cc88, 0 0 10px #00cc88;
     }
 }
```

```html
<head>
  <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<div class="centerit">
    <div id="content">
        <br /><br />
        <h2 style="color: #ff2828;text-align: center;font-family:Bangers;font-weight:400;font-style:normal" class="top-words-home3" >Congratulations and Thank You!</h2>
        <br />
        <h3 class="top-words-home4" style="text-align: center; color: blue; font-weight: bold;"><strong>Watch Your Email Inbox & Spam Folder For An Email From Us!</strong></h3>
        <br />
        <p style="font-size:28px;">Please be advised that we have very limited seating for this webinar.<br />Be sure to look for the followups for this webinar on the day of the webinar and follow the directions very carefully.</p>
        <br /><br />
    </div>
</div>
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```